# Android static function call throws NullPointerException

Tags: android

I have an appwidget, that creates an object (passing its context) and then calling a static method on some other class.

The call to the static method throws NullPointerException and I have no idea why.

Here's the code:

```
public String[] g(int count, Boolean h) {       

    String[] result = MyFactory.g(mContext, mDb, count, h);

    if (result != null) {
        m = result.length;
    }
    else {
        m = 0;
    }

    return result;

}
```

The exception is thrown at MyFactory.g . g is a static function.

What can be null here?

It seems to happen to some of my users, but not on my device... frustrating.

Thanks.

btw: I'm using proguard on my app, is it possible that because of proguard I don't get the entire stack trace (inside the static function) ?

MyFactory class:

```
public class MyFactory {


public static String[] g(Context mContext, SQLiteDatabase db, int count, boolean hasShortcut) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = 
        mContext.getSharedPreferences(A.SHARED_PREFS_NAME, 0);

    int type = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(mContext.getString(R.string.pref_type_key), "0"));


    switch (type) {
        case 1:
            return T1.g(db, count, hasShortcut);

    }

    return D1.g(db, count, hasShortcut);        

}


}
```

Comment: add your logcat and full code

Comment: the logcat is just a nullpointerexception thrown at the line of MyFactory.g .

Comment: even if mDb is null, why would it throw an exception? I'm allowed to pass a null parameter. If it would crash on some line inside MyFactory then I would understand, but it's crashing on the call.

Comment: -1 The most awesome part about programming is debugging. Get friendly with it.

Comment: can you paste the `MyFactory.g` method code ?

Comment: @pst like I wrote, it doesn't happen on my device but on a user's device. I wish I could debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what the problem was, but I just copied the static function code to the non-static calling function and it worked.